# How is the google client application working on android?

Tags: android

Is the gcm-client app keeps listening from the server?

If it does, won't it takes away too much battery power?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.

`Google Cloud Messaging` waits for a message to come in. When one does come in, it is notified by the `Android OS` to wake up because some data has come in. If no data has arrived, then the Android OS will not wake up GCM and so GCM will not consume much power.

`GCM` uses a push model where the cloud pushes to your mobile device so it can just sit around and wait for data to come in. Power usage will scale with messages received, not the time that you've been waiting.